# put two images on the same slide

Tags: beamer, pdftex

sorry to bother you but I'm quite new in Latex. I would like to put two images in a presentation, better in one slide in this way:

```
image1
image2
```

the two images will go one under the other and while I discuss the first image I would like the second to be not totally invisible but opaque.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `setbeamercoverd` to alter the coverd options:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}

\begin{document}
 \frame{
  \setbeamercovered{transparent=50}% if here: local (only this frame)
  \includegraphics{test}

   \uncover<2->{\includegraphics{test}}
  }

\end{document}
```

[image]